# EF Core Unit Of Work pattern scoped context disposed during request

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm having trouble with a Scoped context getting disposed before a controller route has finished executing...

This is example code that demonstrates the problem as I can't share the real code

I have a Unit of Work that would 'wrap' the repository layer

```cs
public interface IUnitOfWork
{
    void Dispose();
    bool GetContextDisposed();
}

public class UnitOfWork : IDisposable, IUnitOfWork
{
    private ISomeContext _context;
    public ISomeRepository someRepository;
    public UnitOfWork(ISomeContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        someRepository = new SomeRepository(_context);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _context.Dispose();
    }

    public bool GetContextDisposed()
    {
        return _context.GetDisposed(); 
    }
}
```

Context

```cs
public interface ISomeContext
{
    void Dispose();
    public bool GetDisposed();
}

public class SomeContext : IDisposable, ISomeContext
{
    private bool isDisposed = false;
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Dispose being called on Context");
        isDisposed = true;
    }

    public bool GetDisposed()
    {
        return isDisposed;
    }
}
```

These are both registered as scoped as I want to get one per request to an endpoint

```cs
services.AddScoped<ISomeContext, SomeContext>();
services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
```

Now in my controller I have a long running task that happens and after it is finished I need to do some cleanup but I want to go ahead and respond to the request so it doesn't have to wait for these long running tasks to complete

```cs
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _uow;
    public ValuesController(IUnitOfWork uow)
    {
        _uow = uow;
    }
        
    [Route("Test")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetTest()
    {
        Task myTask = SomeLongRunningThing();
        try
        {
            return Ok();
        }
        finally
        {
            Response.OnCompleted(async () =>
            {
                Task continueTask = myTask.ContinueWith(async (task) =>
                {
                    await Task.Delay(5000);
                    Console.WriteLine("Checking if context is disposed...");
                    Console.WriteLine(_uow.GetContextDisposed());
                });
                await myTask;
                await continueTask;
            });
        }
        Console.WriteLine("End of route");
    }

    private Task SomeLongRunningThing()
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Task.Delay(10000);
        });
    }
}
```

The output shows

> Dispose being called on Context
> Dispose being called on Context
> Dispose being called on Context
> Dispose being called on Context
> Checking if context is disposed...
> True

What could be causing the context to be disposed before the route is fully completed?
I've tried messing with the lifetimes but it doesn't seem any lifetime helps the situation.

Version Stuff

- .net core 3.1 MVC
- Running on Windows 10

Thanks

Comment: My understanding is that the unit of work and the DbContext need to be registered as Transient because you don't want the context to be inadvertently shared with something else in the same scope, which could conflate its changes with yours. Is there a specific need for them to be Scoped? I'm not sure Transient will fix this issue, only that it will be less wrong as it pertains to the UoW pattern.

Comment: You may be right, I have it scoped based on what is said here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-6.0#service-lifetimes
"By default, Entity Framework contexts are added to the service container using the scoped lifetime because web app database operations are normally scoped to the client request. "
But either way, if I swap both the context and unit of work to be Transient instead of Scoped it doesn't resolve this particular issue

Answer (score 1):

Figured out something that works for my use case, I think...

I inject `IServiceProvider` into my controller as well

```
private readonly IUnitOfWork _uow;
        private readonly IServiceProvider _services;
        public ValuesController(IUnitOfWork uow, IServiceProvider services)
        {
            _uow = uow;
            _services = services;
        }
```

Then during the `Task.Run(() => {})` and `ContinueWith(async (task) => {})` I can use it to create a new scope and get an IUnitOfWork

```
private Task SomeLongRunningThing(OperationContext context)
        {
            return Task.Run(() =>
            {
                using (var scope = _services.CreateScope())
                {
                    IUnitOfWork uow = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IUnitOfWork>();
                    OperationContext.Current = context;
                    Task.Delay(10000);
                }
            });
        }
```

```
Task continueTask = myTask.ContinueWith(async (task) =>
            {
                using(var scope = _services.CreateScope())
                {
                    IUnitOfWork uow = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IUnitOfWork>();
                    await Task.Delay(5000);
                    Console.WriteLine("Checking if context is disposed...");
                    Console.WriteLine(uow.GetContextDisposed());
                }
            });
```